# Can't access System.IO in Shared Project

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, shared-project

I'm currently using `Xamarin` to make some quick mobile application. However, I'm trying to use `Shared Project` in order to write some JSON data in a file in both Android and iOS.

If I put my object serializing data and saving it inside of two distinct Class in the Android or iOS part it works well.

However, when I use

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, contents);
```

Which is contained in `System.IO` I got the following error :

```
The name 'File' does not exist in the current context
```

I believed that I could use everything in `Shared Project` but this does not seem to be the case. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You're doing things right but I/O isn't as _shared_ as you (we) may wish. Take a look to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/. I never played _seriously_ with Xamarin then I can't provide anything more than a link, sorry.

Comment: It should work if it is actually a shared project type. Not PCL or library